# discriminant and roots in mips assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am new to Mips Assembly and i want to write a program that calculates the roots of a quadratic function. I've found the discriminant but now i want to check if >0, <0 or =0 and find x1,x2. I dont know how to find the root of discriminant. I googled for sqrt but i think that this version doesnt support the command. I am using qtspim.
Edit: The roots have to be integers

```
.data
msg_read_a: .asciiz"dwse arithmo a:"
msg_read_b: .asciiz"dwse arithmo b:"
msg_read_x1: .asciiz"dwse diastima x1:"
msg_read_x2: .asciiz"dwse diastima x2:"

akuro: .asciiz"h sunartish den mhdenizetai"
midenizetai: .asciiz"h sunarthsh midenizetai"

.text 
main:

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg_read_a    #α
syscall
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t0,$v0

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg_read_b    #β
syscall 
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t1,$v0

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg_read_x1    #διαστημα χ1
syscall
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t2,$v0

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg_read_x2    #διαστημα χ2
syscall
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t3,$v0


mul $t5,$t1,$t1
mul $t6,$t1,0  #b^2
li $t7,4        #+4
mul $t7,$t7,$t6 

sub $t8,$t5,$t7 #τ8=διακρινουσα

bgt $t8,0, mega
blt $t8,0, mikro
beq $t8,0, isioi

mega: mul $t5,$t1,-1  #-b
syscall
j exodos
iso: mul $t5,$t1,-1  #-b
mul $t6,$t0,2
div $t7,$t5,$t6
syscall
j exodos
exodos: li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: Are you aware that the roots may not be integers? Are you familiar with floating point instructions? Are you intentionally using integer arithmetic instead of floating point arithmetic here?

Comment: U are right, i forgot to mention that the roots have to be integers @Ruud Helderman

Comment: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root#Example_implementation_in_C

Comment: What does multiplying by 0 accomplish for you?

Comment: @ErikEidt cause its my first day in assembly i wanted to have the formula of discriminant as it is, the function that i want to solve is ax^2+bx, so u are right and its a waste of time.

Comment: `mul` by `-1` is also a slow and unusual way to do `subu $t5, $zero, $t1`.  Unlike multiplying by zero, it's not useless, though.